# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.quarkus.paths.PathCollection io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.QuarkusBootstrap.getApplicationRoot()'

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

```
this is our dependencies in pom.xml .
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-zipfile</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-narayana-jta</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm-deployment -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-deployment</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.276</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/s3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.40</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.276</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sns -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.714</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-agroal-spi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-agroal-spi</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-datasource-deployment -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-datasource-deployment</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-core-deployment -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-core-deployment</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-jdbc-postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

build failure error encountered after try to build this quarkus application.
the error is"Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.6.0.Final:build (default) on project irxpp-jobs: Execution default of goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.6.0.Final:build failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.6.0.Final:build: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'io.quarkus.paths.PathCollection io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.QuarkusBootstrap.getApplicationRoot()'".

Comment: please share full pom.xml

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your quostion? You have postet your pom.xml and an error but no question. It will be hard to answer without a quistion or your build command.

Comment: not able to share full pom.xml due to company policies. my question is I have added this dependendency <dependency>
   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-core-deployment</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.6.Final</version>
  </dependency>  after that I was tried to build my quarkus application using the eclipse (maven build(alt+shift+x,M)). getting the above error.@LinFelix

Comment: Make sure all your Quarkus dependencies are the same version. NoSuchMethodErrors are usually causes by incompatible dependency versions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As @PaulSamsotha mentions, you are likely mixing Quarkus versions in the application dependencies and the maven plugin.